Input Number is not update in Blazor
I hope that i can find an answer here.
I had tried both InputNumber from Microsoft .NET or even NumberInput from Blazor Bootstrap.
<div class="@(IsOpen ? "block" : "hidden") fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
        <div class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
            <div class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>
            <div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-4xl sm:w-full">
                <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                    <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">
                        <EditForm id="@_addOrderItemFormId" EditContext="_editContext" method="post" OnValidSubmit="AddOrderItem" FormName="AddOrderItem">
                            <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
                            <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert"/>
                            <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-5 sm:text-left">
                                <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900" id="modal-title">
                                    Product Information
                                </h3>
                                <div class="mt-2 grid gap-4 sm:grid-cols-4 sm:gap-2">
                                    <div class="flex items-center space-x-2 sm:col-span-1">
                                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                                            <label id="OrderQuantity" class="block font-bold leading-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Quantity</label>
                                            <InputNumber
                                                @bind-Value="@OrderItemRequestInput.Quantity"
                                                type="number"
                                                name="OrderQuantity"
                                                id="OrderQuantity"
                                                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex items-center sm:col-span-2">
                                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500 w-full">
                                            <label for="ProductName" class="block font-bold leading-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Product Name</label>
                                            <InputText
                                                @bind-Value="@Product.Name"
                                                type="ProductName"
                                                name="ProductName"
                                                id="ProductName"
                                                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500"
                                                placeholder="Business Standard"
                                                readonly
                                                required/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex items-center sm:col-span-1">
                                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                                            <label for="UnitId" class="block font-bold leading-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Billing Cycle</label>
                                            <InputSelect
                                                @bind-Value="@OrderItemRequestInput.UnitId"
                                                name="UnitId"
                                                id="UnitId"
                                                required
                                                disabled
                                                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500">
                                                
                                                <option value="8C8DC6AD-482D-EF11-86C3-00224892CB72" selected="@(CurrentSelectedCatalog is { TermDuration: "P1M", TermBillingCycle: "Monthly" } ? "selected" : null)">Month</option>
                                                <option value="8D8DC6AD-482D-EF11-86C3-00224892CB72" selected="@(CurrentSelectedCatalog is { TermDuration: "P1Y", TermBillingCycle: "Annual" } ? "selected" : null)">Annual</option>
                                                <option value="8E8DC6AD-482D-EF11-86C3-00224892CB72" selected="@(CurrentSelectedCatalog is { TermDuration: "P1Y", TermBillingCycle: "Monthly" } ? "selected" : null)">Annual billed monthly</option>
                                            </InputSelect>
                                            <ValidationMessage For="() => OrderItemRequestInput.UnitId" class="text-danger"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="my-4 border-t border-gray-400 w-1/2 mx-auto"></div>

                            <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
                                <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900" id="modal-title">
                                    Order
                                </h3>
                                <div class="mt-2">
                                    <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                                        <InputSelect
                                            @bind-Value="@OrderItemRequestInput.OrderId"
                                            name="OrderId"
                                            id="OrderId"
                                            required
                                            class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500">
                                            <option value="@Guid.Empty">Select order</option>
                                            @if (Orders is { Results: not null })
                                            {
                                                @foreach (var order in Orders.Results)
                                                {
                                                    <option value="@order.Id">@order.Name | @order.TotalPrice</option>
                                                }
                                            }
                                        </InputSelect>
                                        <ValidationMessage For="() => OrderItemRequestInput.OrderId" class="text-danger"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </EditForm>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
                    <button
                        form="@_addOrderItemFormId"
                        type="submit"
                        class="right-3 bottom-3 text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 me-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
                        Add to Order
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-circle btn-ghost absolute right-2 top-2" @onclick="Close">
                        ✕
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@code {
    private EditContext? _editContext;
    [Parameter] public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> IsOpenChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public ProductResponse Product { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public MicrosoftCatalogResponse CurrentSelectedCatalog { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public double CustomerPriceExGst { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Guid? SelectedUnitId { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public PagedResult<SpecificOrderResponse> Orders { get; set; }

    private CreateOrderItemRequest _orderItemRequestInput = new();
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<CreateOrderItemRequest> OrderItemRequestInputChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public CreateOrderItemRequest OrderItemRequestInput
    {
        get => _orderItemRequestInput;
        set
        {
            if (_orderItemRequestInput != value)
            {
                _orderItemRequestInput = value;
                 OrderItemRequestInputChanged.InvokeAsync(value);

            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        OrderItemRequestInput ??= new();
        _editContext = new(OrderItemRequestInput);
        OrderItemRequestInput.Quantity = 1;
        
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private string _addOrderItemFormId = "AddOrderItemFormId";
    private OrderLineItemResponse OrderItemResponse { get; set; }

    private double TotalPrice { get; set; }


    private async Task AddOrderItem(EditContext editContext)
    {
        if (!editContext.Validate())
        {
            return;
        }

        Logger.LogInformation($"OrderItemRequestInput before submission: {JsonSerializer.Serialize(OrderItemRequestInput)}");
        Logger.LogInformation($"Order id {OrderItemRequestInput.OrderId} is selected");
        Logger.LogInformation($"Add {OrderItemRequestInput.Quantity} product: {OrderItemRequestInput.ProductId} to order: {OrderItemRequestInput.OrderId}");
        OrderItemRequestInput.UnitId = SelectedUnitId.Value;
        OrderItemRequestInput.ProductId = Product.ID;
        OrderItemRequestInput.ResellerPrice = (decimal)CustomerPriceExGst;
        try
        {
            OrderItemResponse = await LnkOrderItemService.AddOrderItemIntoOrder(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext, OrderItemRequestInput);
            Console.WriteLine("Result Message: " + OrderItemResponse.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"Add {OrderItemRequestInput.Quantity} product: {OrderItemRequestInput.ProductId} with unit: {OrderItemRequestInput.UnitId} to order: {OrderItemRequestInput.OrderId} has error {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }

    private bool _isLoading = true;

    private async Task OpenModal()
    {
        IsOpen = true;
    }

    private async Task Close()
    {
        IsOpen = false;
        await IsOpenChanged.InvokeAsync(IsOpen);
    }

}

my OrderItemRequest class

public class CreateOrderItemRequest
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    // public String TermDuration { get; set; }
    // public String TermBillingCycle { get; set; }
    public decimal ResellerPrice { get; set; } // This price is CustomerPrice
    public Guid UnitId { get; set; }
    public Guid? IdRelatedLease { get; set; }
}

On the UI, i have tried to put 2 or 3 or even 300. However, the OrderLineItemRequestInput.Quantity is always 1
Is there anything i do wrong?
I try to get input of Quantity from EditForm above.
Edit: I have edited my uploaded code.

You need to post some form of [MRE].  I'm having trouble understanding you're problem and the code.  For example:  Where is _quantity :  Why are you passing around EditContext instances?

Hi Shaun, I have updated it. So pretty much i have a request receive user Quantity  input, I preset the quantity is 1 now. So now every time I/users input another number, it is still 1. If I don't preset the quantity, then now it is always 0. Similar with select order, I read some other threads, it told me to create a <option value="@Guid.Empty">Select the order</option> and list all the others option. Now when i select another order, the OrderId still Guid.Empty. It means the form does not take the value input from users.

Where is the input in your code? Where is the binding statement? That is the important but but you haven't included it in your code example.

Hi, sorry, not sure why it just cut my code, i have updated it again... Can you please help me to check? Thanks for your patience.

You've provided a bit of a wall of code, so without the full context, I may not have found all the issues.
This is wrong.  See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0:
    [Parameter]
    public CreateOrderItemRequest OrderItemRequestInput
    {
        get => _orderItemRequestInput;
        set
        {
            if (_orderItemRequestInput != value)
            {
                _orderItemRequestInput = value;
                 OrderItemRequestInputChanged.InvokeAsync(value);

            }
        }
    }

It should be a simple get/set.
    [Parameter] public CreateOrderItemRequest OrderItemRequestInput { get; set;}

If you want to detect changes to parameters, do it in SetParametersAsync.  Here's some example code:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext">
    @* Your form - use internal _orderItemRequestInput *@
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public CreateOrderItemRequest OrderItemRequestInput { get; set; } = default!;
    private CreateOrderItemRequest? _orderItemRequestInput;
    private EditContext? _editContext;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // Assign the provided parameters to the component properties
        // Should always do first
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(OrderItemRequestInput);

        if (_orderItemRequestInput != this.OrderItemRequestInput)
        {
            _orderItemRequestInput = this.OrderItemRequestInput;
            // Reset the edit context
            _editContext = new(_orderItemRequestInput);
            // do other stuff
        }

        // call base with an empty ParameterView.  We've already set them!
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    public class CreateOrderItemRequest
    {
        // properties
    }
}

